# Where can I find complete micropython documentation

Tags: micropython

Can anybody tell me where there is compete documentation for the micropython specific libraries. The documentation that I can easily find seems to consist mainly of examples.

So for example - you can find several examples that use constants in a bluetooth BLE advertisement but nowhere can you find a complete list of the constants that will be understood by the ble.gap_advertise call.

Comment: Can you elaborate? http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/bluetooth.html#broadcaster-role-advertiser doesn't seem to mention any constants

Answer (score 0):

This is a good website for micropython documentation
https://docs.openmv.io/